# Flask app hangs on request after bundling with cx_freeze

Tags: python, python-2.7, flask, cx-freeze

I've made a Flask app in Python which I want to turn into an exe for distribution, for that I'm trying to use cx_freeze.

When I run the app from Python or Pycharm, it works perfectly, but after I bundle it up, every request just hangs (spins in chrome). I tried debugging it and ended up creating a new flask app with just one route and no other dependencies, and the same thing happens.

Here's the test app I made (`testapp/app.py`):

```
from flask import Flask

# Create flask app
webapp = Flask(__name__)

@webapp.route('/')
def home():
    print "home"
    return 'hello there'
```

The `setup.py` for it:

```
from setuptools import find_packages
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

setup(
    name='testapp',
    description='Test Flask App',
    packages=find_packages(),
    include_package_data=True,
    zip_safe=False,
    install_requires=[
        'Flask',
        'waitress',
    ],
    options={
        "build_exe": {
            "packages": [
                "flask",
                "waitress",
                "threading",
                "os",
            ],
            'include_msvcr': True,
        }
    },
    executables=[
        Executable(
            "run.py",
            icon="icon.ico",
        )
    ]
)
```

And the `run.py` which serves as my entry point

```
from testapp.app import webapp
import sys
import waitress

if __name__ == "__main__":
    PORT = sys.argv[1] if len(sys.argv) > 1 else 8080
    waitress.serve(webapp, port=PORT)
```

I've read a few other questions but it seems to always end up being a templating problem, but this app isn't using templates and neither is my real app.

When I run it normally I get the output below and the page says "hello" to me

```
Serving on http://Desktop-PC:8080
home
```

When I run it as an exe, I get the same console output but the page just hangs.

I'm using `flask==0.12` and `cx-Freeze==5.0.1`

Any ideas on how I can debug this one?

*Edit:*

I've noticed that during build time, I get a lot of warnings about missing packages, but if I try add those packages to my `setup.py`, cx_freeze throws errors about not being able to import them. But if I can't import them, and my app apparently needs them, shouldn't it fail to run normally?

List is a bit long, so it's in a [gist](https://gist.github.com/gricey432/85a6211b25ee1fc341a6d3ac3919b91d)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This ended up being a [bug](https://github.com/anthony-tuininga/cx_Freeze/issues/270) in cx_Freeze `5.0.1` which is now patched in cx_Freeze `5.0.2`.